# What does setuptools.setup do with all the metadata keywords?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

Getting to a point with my project that I want to distribute it, so I am reading the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/) to better familiarize myself with all the information. Eventually I found myself looking at [`distutils.core.setup`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.core) and all the keywords associated with it and it got me wondering:

> What are the keywords used for, where do they go and why do we need them?

After running `sdist` on some temporary scaffolding project, I noticed that a `PKG-INFO` appeared with some of this metadata in it. But thats the only place I could find them after running the command. There is the `upload` command (or I could use `twine`) to get the source distribution onto PyPI, so I suppose maybe its a convention used to pass information that is then parsed and loaded onto the PyPI web page for the distribution?

Comment: Did you delete an earlier version of this question? I was writing an answer and suddenly I received a message on the screen that the question had disappeared. Maybe it was a glitch in Stackoverflow, but if not, please know that it's quite disruptive to delete content that others may interact with.

Comment: @chryss No I did not

Comment: OK, apologies for the implication! Good luck.

Comment: @chryss Do you have an answer that perhaps fits this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I suppose maybe its a convention used to pass information that is then parsed and loaded onto the PyPI web page for the distribution?

You're precisely right. Most of these keywords represent various [core metadata](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/) fields that define all Python package distributions.

These path of this data is roughly this:

- You specify the keywords to the `setup` function;
- This is written to the `PKG-INFO` file when building a distribution;
- When uploading, `twine` reads from `PKG-INFO` to determine all the metadata about your distribution;
- `twine` uploads this metadata along with your `.zip`, `.tar.gz` or `.whl` file
- PyPI stores this metadata in it's database for your project.